# Internal redirect to another virtual host with mod_rewrite (or similar)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I'm trying to get site.com/api to *internally* redirect to api.site.com. Site.com's .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://api.site.com/$1 [P,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have mod_proxy and mod_rewrite installed. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

EDIT: site.com and api.site.com are *on the same server*. I wish to do the redirect as efficiently as possible. If there's a way to pass a request in a certain path directly to a file, ie /srv/www/api.site.com/index.php via mod_rewrite, that would be just as good.

The point of this is to have two separate entities but circumvent javascript's cross-domain policy. Having a delegate is not an option, I want there to be direct communication. JSONP is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out via a url rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /library/api.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

/library/api.php includes the index script in /srv/www/api.site.com/index.php directly. It has to rewrite some of the parameters in $_SERVER, but since the api.site.com's index.php is a singleton, this more than serves my purposes.